# C# MSMQ Message with Binary Body Has Extra Bytes

Tags: c#, msmq

I have some code which receives a byte array from a UDP listener and writes it to a message queue. It seems to be mostly working but when I inspect the message on the queue it has extra bytes preceding my data.

```
byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref endpoint);

Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {endpoint} :");
Console.WriteLine($" {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length)}");

Message msg = new Message();
msg.Body = data;
msg.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();

_queue.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

So when data is {byte[6]} (actually "Hello!"), this is what I see on the queue:

```
00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF .....ÿÿÿ
FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 ÿ.......
00 0F 01 00 00 00 06 00 ........
00 00 02 48 65 6C 6C 6F ...Hello
21 0B                   !.
```

So my Hello! is there but what is that extra preamble?

Comment: Show us you're initializing `listener` and `_queue`

Comment: @nouns You should avoid using `BinaryFormatter` it's obsolete and has [vulnerabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Comment: @DenisMicheal Are you sure the `BinaryMessageFormatter` is related to the `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: Yes @GoodNightNerdPride [BinaryMessageFormatter](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/System.Messaging/System.Messaging/BinaryMessageFormatter.cs#L44C3-L44C3) ,it will use `BinaryFormatter` to Serialize/Deserialize

Comment: This isn't a preamble, it's the other message contents beyond the body itself. You can inspect them if you use the XmlMessageFormatter to produce an XML message.

Comment: That's the pre-amble that BinaryFormatter uses to format the serialized object.